# Remove all non-numeric characters from an NSString, keeping spaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I am trying to remove all of the non-numeric characters from an `NSString`, but I also need to keep the spaces. Here is what I have been using.

```
NSString *strippedBbox = [_bbox stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [_bbox length])];
```

If I give it a NSString of `Test 333 9599 999` It will return `3339599999` but I need to keep the spaces in.

How can I do this?

Comment: iterate through the characters, check if space or digit, append to another string if so.

Comment: Shouldn't the replacement string be a space instead of an empty string?

Comment: Add space to the character class...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Easily done by creating a character set of characters you want to keep and using `invertedSet` to create an "all others" set. Then split the string into an array separated by any characters in this set and reassemble the string again. Sounds complicated but very simple to implement:

```
NSCharacterSet *setToRemove =   
    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789 "];
NSCharacterSet *setToKeep = [setToRemove invertedSet];

NSString *newString = 
        [[someString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:setToKeep]
            componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

result: `333 9599 99`

Comment: This assumes English numeric characters; how easy to adjust would this be to be locale aware?

Comment: Create a mutable copy of `[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]` and add a space to it.

Comment: Updated with a cleaner, shorter version of the same code.

Comment: @dreamlax Slightly less code to just specify the digits in this case. If the set were alpha or alphanumeric, then using a mutable set would be preferable.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons: I was responding to WDUK's question, the `decimalDigitCharacterSet` includes decimal digit characters in other languages such as Indic and Arabic scripts too.

Answer (score 21):

You could alter your first regex to include a space after the 9:

In swift:

```
var str = "test Test 333 9599 999";
val strippedStr = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[^0-9 ]", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil);
// strippedStr = " 33 9599 999"
```

While this leaves the leading space, you could apply a whitespace trimming to deal with that:

```
strippedStr.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
// strippedStr = "33 9599 999"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// Our test string
NSString* _bbox = @"Test 333 9599 999";

// Remove everything except numeric digits and spaces
NSString *strippedBbox = [_bbox stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^\\d ]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [_bbox length])];
// (Optional) Trim spaces on either end, but keep spaces in the middle
strippedBbox = [strippedBbox stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

// Print result
NSLog(@"%@", strippedBbox);
```

This prints `333 9599 999`, which I think is what you're after. It also removes non numeric characters that may be in the middle of the string, such as parentheses.

Comment: Ah, oops, apologies. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 4):

#### For Swift 3.0.1 folks

```
var str = "1 3 6 .599.188-99 "
    str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

Output: `"13659918899"`

*This also trim spaces from string*

Answer (score 3):

try using NSScanner

```
NSString *originalString = @"(123) 123123 abc";
NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString 
    stringWithCapacity:originalString.length];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet 
    characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789 "];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    NSString *buffer;
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
        [strippedString appendString:buffer];
    } else {
        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", strippedString); // "123123123"
```

Comment: This removes spaces and OP wants to keep them.

Comment: @MichałCiuba There, I fixed it.

Comment: It's also pretty hardcore, when `NSString` provides convenience methods that slash the LOC required.

Comment: The [lack of] indentation was driving me nuts, had to fix that too

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString strippedBbox = [_bbox mutableCopy];
NSCharacterSet* charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890 "].invertedSet;

NSUInteger start = 0;
NSUInteger length = _bbox.length;

while(length > 0)
{
    NSRange range = [strippedBbox rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet options:0 range:NSMakeRange(start, length)];

    if(range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        break;
    }

    start += (range.location + range.length);
    length -= range.length;

    [strippedBbox replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In brief, you can use NSCharacterSet to examine only those chars that are interesting to you and ignore the rest.

```
- (void) stripper {

    NSString *inString = @"A1 B2 C3 D4";
    NSString *outString = @"";

    for (int i = 0; i < inString.length; i++) {

        if ([[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[inString characterAtIndex:i]] || [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[inString characterAtIndex:i]]) {

            outString = [outString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[inString characterAtIndex:i]]];
        }
    }
}
```