# Remove all non-numeric characters from a string in swift

Tags: swift, nscharacterset

I have the need to parse some unknown data which should just be a numeric value, but may contain whitespace or other non-alphanumeric characters.

Is there a new way of doing this in Swift? All I can find online seems to be the old C way of doing things.

I am looking at `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` - as I am sure my inputs will only have whitespace/special characters at the start or end of the string. Are there any built in character sets I can use for this? Or do I need to create my own?

I was hoping there would be something like `stringFromCharactersInSet()` which would allow me to specify only valid characters to keep

Answer (score 251, accepted):

> I was hoping there would be something like stringFromCharactersInSet() which would allow me to specify only valid characters to keep.

You can either use `trimmingCharacters` with the `inverted` character set to remove characters from the start or the end of the string. In Swift 3 and later:

```
let result = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted)
```

Or, if you want to remove non-numeric characters anywhere in the string (not just the start or end), you can `filter` the `characters`, e.g. in Swift 4.2.1:

```
let result = string.filter("0123456789.".contains)
```

Or, if you want to remove characters from a `CharacterSet` from anywhere in the string, use:

```
let result = String(string.unicodeScalars.filter(CharacterSet.whitespaces.inverted.contains))
```

Or, if you want to only match valid strings of a certain format (e.g., `####.##`), you could use regular expression. For example, using the newer [regular expression literals](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex) (as discussed in WWDC 2022’s video [Meet Swift Regex](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110358/) and [Swift Regex: Beyond the basics](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110358/)), enclosing the regex with `/` characters:

```swift
if let range = string.firstRange(of: /\d+(\.\d*)?/) {
    let result = string[range] // or `String(string[range])` if you need `String`
}
```

Or, using the old `range(of:options:)` with the `.regularExpression` option:

```swift
if let range = string.range(of: #"\d+(\.\d*)?"#, options: .regularExpression) {
    let result = string[range] // or `String(string[range])` if you need `String`
}
```

The behavior of these different approaches differ slightly, so it just depends on precisely what you're trying to do. Include or exclude the decimal point if you want decimal numbers, or just integers. There are lots of ways to accomplish this.

---

For older, Swift 2 syntax, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36607684/4).

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do `inverted` on the character set in the Swift 3 example?

Comment: @AndyIbanez It's like saying, if "ABC" are the characters I want to keep then trim everything that is not "ABC".

Comment: In Swift 4.2.1 `let result = String(string.characters.filter { "01234567890.".characters.contains($0) })` can be shortened to `let result = string.filter("01234567890.".contains)`

Answer (score 47):

```
let result = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[^0-9]", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
```

**Swift 3**

```
let result = string.replacingOccurrences( of:"[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

You can upvote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30625591/1803879).

Comment: Thanks!  after getting all the Swift3 changes, I was left with this:    myStr.replacingOccurrences( of:"[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)

Answer (score 35):

I prefer [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971505/filter-non-digits-from-string/39474725#39474725), because I like extensions, and it seems a bit cleaner to me. Solution reproduced here:

```
extension String {
    var digits: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
            .joined()
    }
}
```

Comment: seems to strip decimals

Answer (score 26):

You can filter the UnicodeScalarView of the string using the pattern matching operator for ranges, pass a UnicodeScalar ClosedRange from 0 to 9 and initialise a new String with the resulting UnicodeScalarView:

```
extension String {
    private static var digits = UnicodeScalar("0")..."9"
    var digits: String {
        return String(unicodeScalars.filter(String.digits.contains))
    }
}

"abc12345".digits   // "12345"
```

edit/update:

**Swift 4.2**

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
    var digits: Self {
        return filter(("0"..."9").contains)
    }
}
```

or as a mutating method

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
    mutating func removeAllNonNumeric() {
        removeAll { !("0"..."9" ~= $0) }
    }
}
```

---

**Swift 5.2 • Xcode 11.4 or later**

In Swift5 we can use a new Character property called `isWholeNumber`:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
    var digits: Self { filter(\.isWholeNumber) }
}
```

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
    mutating func removeAllNonNumeric() {
        removeAll { !$0.isWholeNumber }
    }
}
```

---

To allow a period as well we can extend Character and create a computed property:

```
extension Character {
    var isDecimalOrPeriod: Bool { "0"..."9" ~= self || self == "." }
}
```

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
    var digitsAndPeriods: Self { filter(\.isDecimalOrPeriod) }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
"abc12345".digits   // "12345"

var str = "123abc0"
str.removeAllNonNumeric()
print(str) //"1230"

"Testing0123456789.".digitsAndPeriods // "0123456789."
```

Comment: Great solution for Swift 5! How can I leave "." or "," within the String, to be able to convert a String to a Double?

Comment: how can i use for negative numbers? like "   -1531 hello "

Answer (score 18):

> `Swift 4`

I found a decent way to *get only **alpha numeric** characters set* from a string. 
For instance:-

```
func getAlphaNumericValue() {

    var yourString  = "123456789!@#$%^&*()AnyThingYouWant"

    let unsafeChars = CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted  // Remove the .inverted to get the opposite result.  

    let cleanChars  = yourString.components(separatedBy: unsafeChars).joined(separator: "")


    print(cleanChars)  // 123456789AnyThingYouWant

}
```

Answer (score 12):

A solution using the `filter` function and `rangeOfCharacterFromSet`

```
let string = "sld [f]34é7*˜µ"

let alphaNumericCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
let filteredCharacters = string.characters.filter {
  return  String($0).rangeOfCharacterFromSet(alphaNumericCharacterSet) != nil
}
let filteredString = String(filteredCharacters) // -> sldf34é7µ
```

To filter for only numeric characters use

```
let string = "sld [f]34é7*˜µ"

let numericSet = "0123456789"
let filteredCharacters = string.characters.filter {
  return numericSet.containsString(String($0))
}
let filteredString = String(filteredCharacters) // -> 347
```

or

```
let numericSet : [Character] = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
let filteredCharacters = string.characters.filter {
  return numericSet.contains($0)
}
let filteredString = String(filteredCharacters) // -> 347
```

Comment: I don't want any alpha values, although I don't expect any

Comment: Please be more specific. The headline says `non-alphanumeric` ;-) I edited the answer for numeric characters.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

But without extensions or componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet which doesn't read as well.

```
let allowedCharSet = NSCharacterSet.letters.union(.whitespaces)
let filteredText = String(sourceText.unicodeScalars.filter(allowedCharSet.contains))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let string = "+1*(234) fds567@-8/90-"
let onlyNumbers = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()

print(onlyNumbers) // "1234567890"
```

or

```
extension String {

  func removeNonNumeric() -> String {
    return self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
  }
}

let onlyNumbers = "+1*(234) fds567@-8/90-".removeNonNumeric() 
print(onlyNumbers)// "1234567890"
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3, filters all except numbers

```
let myString = "dasdf3453453fsdf23455sf.2234"
let result = String(myString.characters.filter { String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")) != nil })
print(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.2

```
let numericString = string.filter { (char) -> Bool in
    return char.isNumber
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this...

```
let string = "[,myString1. \"" // string : [,myString1. " 
let characterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "[,. \"")
let finalString = (string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(characterSet) as NSArray).componentsJoinedByString("") 
print(finalString)   
//finalString will be "myString1"
```

Comment: I don't have a full idea of what characters may be in the string - and I only want numeric values at the end. This would need me to list all the characters I don't want.. there are a lot of characters that could be

Answer (score 2):

The issue with Rob's first solution is `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only filters the ends of the string rather than throughout, as stated in Apple's documentation:

> Returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the receiver characters contained in a given character set.

Instead use [`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1410120-componentsseparatedbycharactersi?language=objc) to first isolate all non-occurrences of the character set into arrays and subsequently join them with an empty string separator:

```
"$$1234%^56()78*9££".componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789").invertedSet)).joinWithSeparator("")
```

Which returns `123456789`

Comment: No need to use `NSCharacterSet`. But your answer is the best. Here's a general version:
`extension String {
    func removingCharactersNot(in charSet: CharacterSet) -> String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: charSet.inverted).joined(separator: "")
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

```
extension String {
    var keepNumericsOnly: String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted).joined(separator: "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.0 version

```
extension String {
    var numbers: String {
        return String(describing: filter { String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")) != nil })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4

**String.swift**

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    func removeCharacters(from forbiddenChars: CharacterSet) -> String {
        let passed = self.unicodeScalars.filter { !forbiddenChars.contains($0) }
        return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(passed))
    }

    func removeCharacters(from: String) -> String {
        return removeCharacters(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: from))
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
let character = "1Vi234s56a78l9"
        let alphaNumericSet = character.removeCharacters(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
        print(alphaNumericSet) // will print: 123456789

        let alphaNumericCharacterSet = character.removeCharacters(from: "0123456789")
        print("no digits",alphaNumericCharacterSet) // will print: Vishal
```

Comment: Initializing a new UnicodeScalarView  is pointless. The result of the filter it is already a UnicodeScalarView. `return String(passed)`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let digitChars  = yourString.components(separatedBy:
        CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 Version**

```
extension String
{
    func trimmingCharactersNot(in charSet: CharacterSet) -> String
    {
        var s:String = ""
        for unicodeScalar in self.unicodeScalars
        {
            if charSet.contains(unicodeScalar)
            {
                s.append(String(unicodeScalar))
            }
        }
        return s
    }
}
```