# What is the best way to get a Swift string into a swift-currency/USD format?

Tags: swift

How do I get a string into a 'currency' format USD(xxx)?
I am trying to use the following library:
https://github.com/peek-travel/swift-currency

I want to be able to take a string:

```
var testStr1 = "$30.01"
var testStr2 = "$ 30.01"
```

and convert this into a currency as I have read from several posts using a double or float is bad, but if I start with a String, what else can I convert it to?

I thought I could use the "import Currency" library to do this, but this is not working.

```
let updatedString = testStr1.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "") 
                        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
                        formatter.locale = Locale.current // USA: Locale(identifier: "en_US")
                        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
                        let number = formatter.number(from: test)
var dollars = USD(updatedString)
```

How do I get a string into a 'currency' format USD(xxx)? If there is a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: "but this is not working" - what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic concept presented by Himanshu works fine, but your problem isn't necessarily making use of an appropriate formatter, but how to fix your input, as the formatter expects a `NSNumber` and not a `String`.

So a quick internet check had me looking at [Remove all non-numeric characters from a string in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594179/remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-swift)

So I could take a `String`, filter out all the "non numerical" junk and then make a `Double` out of it.

```
let input = Double(value.filter("0123456789.".contains))
```

from there I was able to borrow the concept from Himanshu and make a simple `format` function

```
func format(_ value: String, locale: Locale = Locale.current) -> String? {
    
    guard let input = Double(value.filter("0123456789.".contains)) else { return nil }

    //value.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    
    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    
    currencyFormatter.locale = locale
    
    return currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: input))
}
```

I then made use of a Playground to test it using

```
var testStr1 = "$30.01"
var testStr2 = "$ 30.01"

format(testStr1, locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US")) // $30.01
format(testStr2, locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US")) // $30.01

format(testStr1, locale: Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")) // 30,01 €
format(testStr2, locale: Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")) // 30,01 €

format(testStr1, locale: Locale(identifier: "de_DE")) // 30,01 €
format(testStr2, locale: Locale(identifier: "de_DE")) // 30,01 €
```

Now, if you specifically want to use `USD(xxx)` as the format, then you could simply use a basic `NumberFormatter` and generate your own `String` from the resulting conversion of the input to a `Double`

> I have read from several posts using a double or float is bad

So, yes, maintaining a currency value as a `Double` or `Float` is generally a bad idea, currency values are typically maintained as a `Int` or `Long`, but this is due to how `Double` and `Float` representation works in computers, for the, general, presentation, you should be fine, but each use case needs be assessed.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion and explanation.

Comment: @HimanshuPatel I thought you wanted the result as USD ... using the currency code. So what is the expected output `"USD $30.01"`?

Comment: @madprogrammer. Remember that Swift is a type inferred language `locale: Locale = .current` and there is no need to initialize a new `NSNumber`. you can use Formatter's method `string(for: Any)` and pass the double

Comment: Another thing that I would definetly fix in this code is that every time you call this method it will create a new Number Formatter

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried `string(for: Any)` and it gave me a compiler error - or I was using the wrong func :P - in any case - it works

Comment: @MadProgrammer I  am not sure what you did wrong. I never use string from method. You can check all my posts All of them I use string(for: value)

Comment: @LeoDabus *"Another thing that I would definetly fix in this code is that every time you call this method it will create a new Number Formatter "* - Yes, I agree, but this is StackOverFlow, not "how you should code properly flow" :P - where we present ideas to help solve problems, after which developers are expected to then go an expand on and fit into their particular use case - just my point of view :P

Answer (score 1):

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
// localize to your grouping and decimal separator
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current

// We'll force unwrap with the !, if you've got defined data you may need more 
error checking
let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: 9999.99)!
print(priceString) // Displays $9,999.99 in the US locale

**Forcing a Custom Locale**
You can override the users locale to display specific currency formats by changing the Locale using the identifier.

currencyFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
if let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: 9999.99) {
    print(priceString) // Displays 9 999,99 € in the French locale
}

currencyFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
if let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: 9999.99) {
    print(priceString) // Displays 9.999,99 € in the German locale
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to start with the test strings I have in my OP that begin with strings that I want to convert to USD?