# How to remove all characters from a String in a CharacterSet in Swift

Tags: swift

How do you delete all the characters from a String in Swift using a CharacterSet?

```
let characterSet = CharacterSet.letters.inverted
let string = "Hello123"

// Does a function like this exist?
string.removeCharacters(in: characterSet)
```

Comment: One solution can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36607684/20287183).

Comment: `string.filter { !$0.isLetter }`